# Razor intellisense error: Feature 'extension method' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Goal:

- Use cshtml `Razor` templates to format data
- Embed cshtml Razor templates in Class Library as `Embedded Resources`
- Use `Linq` statements and extension methods in the cshtml template

I created a new class library project, then adapted [Scott Hanselman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) instructions on how to integrate MVC3 into a WebForms application to get it to work in a Class Library.  Then I use the NuGet package RazorEngine to apply the template to an object.

So far it works great, with one hiccup: *The intellisense does not recognize Linq statements or extension methods* (a pretty important part of MVC) when editing cshtml files.

So for the following cshtml file:

```
@model Customer[]

@Model.Count()

@if (Model.Where(customer => customer.Type == 'New').Any())
{
    <span>Found at least one new customer.</span>
}
```

...it displays the following errors:

`Feature 'extension method' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification`

`Feature 'lambda expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification`

**Does anyone know what I'm missing?**  Thank you in advance--I've spent hours searching for the answer to this.

---

### Some additional details

The following is my `web.config` in the **Views** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>  ...  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I added a `web.config` file to the root of the project. It contains the following:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  ...
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>
...
</configuration>
```

And here are the references for the project:

[image: Project References]

The Class Library has a target framework of `.NET Framework 4` and under Advanced Build Settings, the Language Version is set to `C# 3.0`.

### Update

The project builds and runs properly when using extension methods and Linq.  It's just the intellisense that is throws the error.

Comment: Do you have any `system.codedom` in the config file(s)?

Comment: Hi Marc, I do not have a system.codedom element in any of the config files. Is it necessary?

Comment: no; quite the opposite - the default web.config should handle this; I was just concerned it could be there *making* it use C# 2.0

Comment: Check your build/Project properties I'm curious if there's any rule or fxcop integration to force 2.0 spec?

Comment: I can't find anything at all in the build or project properties that might be forcing 2.0... Checked the source of the .vsproj file, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple hours more of tinkering, I found it had something to do with standard Visual Studio extensions not loading correctly.

I was receiving the error:

> 'VSTS for Database Professionals Sql Server Data-tier Application' package did not load correctly

I found the answer on [on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532121/tons-of-package-did-not-load-correctly-errors).

**How to fix**

1) Run the following installers from the Visual Studio media:

> \WCU\DAC\DACFramework_enu.msi
>
> \WCU\DAC\DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi
>
> \WCU\DAC\TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi

2) Restart VS

Hope this can be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 30):

The key of solving this issue is adding the following tag to your app.config or web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

Note: In some cases, unloading and reloading the project is required.

Comment: For a console app using RazorEngine these 3 lines inside app.config were enough to remove the VS warning.

Comment: @springy76 I can confirm, the key ingredient is `targetFramework="4.0"` in app.config. Thank you!

Comment: Fixed the issue for me as well, but I had to restart VS, after I changed the `App.config`.

Comment: @hofmeister I can confirm had to restart VS for this to take effect, but it did the trick.

Comment: This worked after I unloaded and reloaded the project. Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

I tried all of the solutions to this error that I could find everywhere on the web and had no luck.

I finally got this error to disappear (and my IntelliSense to work) by copying the extra MVC configuration blocks from my project's web.config file to my project's app.config file.

Seems Visual Studio does not respect web.config (at least some of its parts) in a plain old C# library project.

My project's app.config file looks like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Same.  I had to close and re-open VS after changing app.config for things to start working.

Answer (score 8):

The solution for me was to change the project type

1.Unload the project

2.Edit project

3.Add line below (depending on your project MVC version) right after ProjectGuid

MVC 4

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

MVC 3

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

**@Matt**

Try adding this to the Web.Config in the Root of the project (not in the Views Folder)

```
<configuration>
...
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>


...  
</configuration>
```

Comment: This did help... but it's still not recognizing Linq statements, or the 'var' type declaration.  Are these working in your project?

Comment: Erm, try this... Go to, Project Properties > Advanced Build Settings and set the Language Version  to default, this should be C# 4. In theory this shouldn't make a difference because lambdas was added in c# 3 but this is the only difference I can see from my project to yours.

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly this problem in our Project today - it could be replicated across team members so was not an install issue.  Intellisense is compiling the pages to 2.0 code not CS# 3.

I tracked it down to adding a Web Reference to the Class Project (using MVCContrib to have it as a reference library as per http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/)

Took out the WebReference and moved it to another project and fixed the problem, took quite a bit of hunting so hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I think I have the same problem as you. I am using mvccontrib and cannot get linq to work in my views. Could you explain how you fixed your problem in more detail?

Comment: Hi Tyler, I had added a WebReference to the Portable Areas Project, if you haven't added a WebReference to your project it's unlikely to be the same issue as me (to fix it I simply moved the WebReference to a different project).

Having said that I've certainly had a bunch of issues around trying to get it to work consistently (and it's literally just broken again).

Can you describe in a bit more detail what's happening for you, does it work once compiled or it never works?

Answer (score 1):

Add a “system.codedom” section to your config file (app.config in a Console Application) eg:

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs;cshtml" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
<providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.5"/>
<providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
</compiler>
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Comment: Works when you reload the project, not before.