# RazorEngine 3.2.0: Razor Namespace not found in .cshtml File

Tags: razor, intellisense, razorengine

I'm using **RazorEngine** 3.2.0 in a **Class Library project**.

I resolved some Class Library related issues by following the following answer to the following SO-question: [Razor intellisense error: Feature 'extension method' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568347/razor-intellisense-error-feature-extension-method-cannot-be-used-because-it-i)

### Problem

I try to use the `@inherits` keyword. If I **just** write the full qualified name for the **view-class**, **intellisense works**. If I try to inherit from `RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase<T>` it seems that the whole **RazorEngine-Assemlby isn't resolved**.

The Template looks like this:

```
@inherits RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase<ViewModels.PrintCatalogData>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

At **Runtime it works** - just **intellisense is failing**.

### Question

What is needed that the intellisense recognizes the RazorEngine-Assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @inherits probably does not like the fully qualified name. Try adding the namespace RazorEngine.Templating to your web.config and then remove the fully qualified name from the view template.

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
     <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc,    Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
          <add namespace="Assemblies"/>
          <add namespace="RazorEngine.Templating"/>
          <add namespace="Resources"/>
        </namespaces>
     </pages>
```