# Error when using LINQ in asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have just begun working on a asp.net 4.5 (C#) webpage. I have just beginning to learn LINQ. To make sure I am doing everything right I pasted this code (from a Microsoft tutorial into a code file) :

```
int[] numbers = new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var numQuery =
            from num in numbers
            where (num % 2) == 0
            select num;
```

However everything is not right because it says System.LINQ does not exist and intelisense gives me this error when I hover over the keyword from : Feature 'query expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 language specification.  I feel like I am missing a reference.

Comment: Did you try adding a reference ?using System.Data.Linq

Comment: what version of .NET Framework you are using?

Comment: [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568347/razor-intellisense-error-feature-extension-method-cannot-be-used-because-it-i) may help

Comment: I am using asp.net 4.5 and It says System.Data. LINQ does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a [read through this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546156.aspx)

To enable basic LINQ functionality

- In a Visual Basic or C# project, click the Project menu, and then click Add Reference.
- In the Add Reference dialog box, click the .NET tab, scroll to System.Core.dll, and then click it. Click OK.
- Add a using directive or Imports statement for System.Linq to your source code file or project.