# Lamba Expression cannot be used because it is not the part of the ISO -2 C# language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to sort the list by date in my view, Below is the code I am using

```
@foreach (var books in store.BookList.OrderBy(j=>j.Date))
{
    <td>@(books.Count == -1 ? "--" : books.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))</td>
}
```

Solution is building succesfully and functionality is working as expected but in errorlist window i am getting below error.

> "Lamba Expression cannot be used because it is not the part of the ISO -2 C# language"

Comment: Why don't you want to sort your model in Controller Action?

Comment: Controller is used by others too and they don't this to get sort..

Comment: Which version of VS you are using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Best would be to have a derived Controller Action that contains the Sorting.
EG. Index(){return View("",UnSortedModel);}
IndexSorted{return View("Index",SortedModel);}

Comment: This Book object is nested into 3 list in the model and sorting in controller might degrade the performance..

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392105/asp-net-mvc-razor-errors-after-fresh-installation-of-visual-studio-2013-on-windo

Comment: What do you mean _Controller is used by others too_? The view is generated by an action method in the controller and that action method returns this view, so the logic should be in the method, not the view.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I am building a html string using Razor engine by passing List of Object. My object structure MainStore - List<Store -- List<Book>>.. Don't you think if i sort this date in controller Performance might degrade? Actually my code is working and building fine but when ErrorList list that's error..

Comment: No it wont. If anything, what your currently doing will degrade performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a code block in the View On the Top

```
@{
var list=store.BookList.OrderBy(j=>j.Date);
}
```

The variable list here is more like a variable, which can be used anywhere in the following View.

Comment: How does this matter? Its still not working for me. Strange thing is its working fine and building successfully.