# lambda expression and the model keyword cannot be used in strongly typed views inside a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class-library, strongly-typed-view

i created a strongly typed view inside a class library  project everything works fine i can add the `@model myPoject.etc.etc` intellisense is working fine i can use Html helpers etc.

But when i create the form for the type in the view i cannot use the "model" keyword inside my HtmlHelper like that `(model => model.Name)`  and i cannnot use  lambda exrpression it tells me:

> "The features lambda expression is not available in c#2 use c#3 or
>   greater version "

And when add the parameters to my `TextBoxFor` helpers it becomes underlined  and it tells me

> "A reference  to type Func<> declares that it is defined in mscorlib ,
>   but it is missing ."

Ps: in advanced build settings i use c# 6 and am using vs 2015. and thank you.

Comment: What is the framework version?. It seems 2.0.

Comment: thank you for replying but in project properties in  ApplicationTab  , target framework is 4.5.2.

Comment: Some info in this question, though no accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568347/razor-intellisense-error-feature-extension-method-cannot-be-used-because-it-i

Comment: What is your `targetFramework` in your web.config?

Comment: Thank you steve the link was helpful , i just changed the app.config file and errors are gone.

Answer (score 2):

to fix this problem i changed the app.config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```